# Filter array by obj field and get new array with this obj field

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter, array-filter

I have const data, and i need filter cards array by obj field company 
For example by company: 'Symu.co'

```
const data = {
  lanes: [
        {
            id: 'lane1',
            header: 'Quened',
            label: '',
            cards: [
                {id: 'Task1', title: 'Wordpress theme', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'lane2',
        header: 'Planning',
        label: '',
        cards: [
            {id: 'Task2', title: 'Landing page', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'jolene'},
            {id: 'Task3', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'},
            {id: 'Task4', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Microsoft', price: 1500, user: 'john'},
            {id: 'Task5', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'dominic'},
        ]
    },

    {
        id: 'lane3',
        header: 'Design',
        label: '',
        cards: [
            {id: 'Task6', title: 'New Logo', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
            {id: 'Task7', title: 'New website', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'dominic'},
            {id: 'Task8', title: 'New website', company: 'Themeforest', price: 1500, user: 'john'},
            {id: 'Task9', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'jolene'},
        ]
    },

    {
        id: 'lane4',
        header: 'Development',
        label: '()',
        cards: [
            {id: 'Task10', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'john'},
            {id: 'Task11', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
            {id: 'Task12', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'dominic'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'lane5',
        header: 'Testing',
        label: '()',
        cards: [
            {id: 'Task13', title: 'Landing page', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'},

        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'lane6',
        header: 'Production',
        label: '()',
        cards: [
            {id: 'Task14', title: 'Landing page', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'jolene'},
            {id: 'Task15', title: 'New website', company: 'Themeforest', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
            {id: 'Task16', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'lane7',
        header: 'Completed',
        label: '()',
        cards: [
            {id: 'Task17', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'john'},
            {id: 'Task18', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
        ]
    },
]
```

};

My code , but i don`t know how to right do it

```
 for(let i = 0; i < data.lanes.length; i++) {
                var changeCards = data.lanes[i].cards.filter(function(obj) {
                    return obj.company === 'Symu.co';
                    console.log(changeCards);
                });
            }
```

in output i need to get new var   new array as example
in output i need to get new var   new array as example
in output i need to get new var   new array as example
in output i need to get new var   new array as example
in output i need to get new var   new array as example
in output i need to get new var   new array as example
in output i need to get new var   new array as example

```
  var newArray = {
            lanes: [
                {
                    id: 'lane1',
                    header: 'Quened',
                    label: '',
                    cards: [
                        {id: 'Task1', title: 'Wordpress theme', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'

},
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'lane2',
            header: 'Planning',
            label: '',
            cards: [
                {id: 'Task3', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'}
            ]
        },

        {
            id: 'lane3',
            header: 'Design',
            label: '',
            cards: [
            ]
        },

        {
            id: 'lane4',
            header: 'Development',
            label: '()',
            cards: [
                {id: 'Task11', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'lane5',
            header: 'Testing',
            label: '()',
            cards: [
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'lane6',
            header: 'Production',
            label: '()',
            cards: [
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 'lane7',
            header: 'Completed',
            label: '()',
            cards: [
                {id: 'Task18', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},
            ]
        },
    ]
};
```

But i dont know how to do it

Help please!

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to provide code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you problem may be found.

Comment: Posting the code itself is much easier to work with than screenshots.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I edit  what i want to get in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions `reduce`, `forEach` and `filter` to build the desired output.

```js
const data = {    lanes: [    {        id: 'lane1',        header: 'Quened',        label: '',        cards: [            {id: 'Task1', title: 'Wordpress theme', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},        ]    },    {        id: 'lane2',        header: 'Planning',        label: '',        cards: [            {id: 'Task2', title: 'Landing page', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'jolene'},            {id: 'Task3', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'},            {id: 'Task4', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Microsoft', price: 1500, user: 'john'},            {id: 'Task5', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'dominic'},        ]    },    {        id: 'lane3',        header: 'Design',        label: '',        cards: [            {id: 'Task6', title: 'New Logo', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},            {id: 'Task7', title: 'New website', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'dominic'},            {id: 'Task8', title: 'New website', company: 'Themeforest', price: 1500, user: 'john'},            {id: 'Task9', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'jolene'},        ]    },    {        id: 'lane4',        header: 'Development',        label: '()',        cards: [            {id: 'Task10', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'john'},            {id: 'Task11', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},            {id: 'Task12', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'dominic'},        ]    },    {        id: 'lane5',        header: 'Testing',        label: '()',        cards: [            {id: 'Task13', title: 'Landing page', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'},        ]    },    {        id: 'lane6',        header: 'Production',        label: '()',        cards: [            {id: 'Task14', title: 'Landing page', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'jolene'},            {id: 'Task15', title: 'New website', company: 'Themeforest', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},            {id: 'Task16', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'lyall'},        ]    },    {        id: 'lane7',        header: 'Completed',        label: '()',        cards: [            {id: 'Task17', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'john'},            {id: 'Task18', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle'},        ]    },]};

function filterBy(target) {
  return data.lanes.reduce((a, {id, header, label, cards}) => {
    a.lanes.push({id, header, label, cards: cards.filter(({company}) => company === target)});
    return a;
  }, {lanes: []});
}

var result = filterBy('Symu.co');
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can y explain how work var result = Object.keys(data).reduce((a, k)

Comment: @ВоваМагдич I've removed the `Object.keys`.

Comment: can i  this example   rewrite as function that take argument string?

Comment: thx a lot man)  I  start learn react and js  and  can u advice me something)

Comment: @ВоваМагдич start to learn js first and visit the site of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredCards = cards.filter({ company } => company === 'Google');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = { lanes: [ { id: 'lane1', header: 'Quened', label: '', cards: [ { id: 'Task1', title: 'Wordpress theme', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle' }, ] }, { id: 'lane2', header: 'Planning', label: '', cards: [ { id: 'Task2', title: 'Landing page', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'jolene' }, { id: 'Task3', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'lyall' }, { id: 'Task4', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Microsoft', price: 1500, user: 'john' }, { id: 'Task5', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'dominic' }, ] }, { id: 'lane3', header: 'Design', label: '', cards: [ { id: 'Task6', title: 'New Logo', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'michelle' }, { id: 'Task7', title: 'New website', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'dominic' }, { id: 'Task8', title: 'New website', company: 'Themeforest', price: 1500, user: 'john' }, { id: 'Task9', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'jolene' }, ] }, { id: 'lane4', header: 'Development', label: '()', cards: [ { id: 'Task10', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'john' }, { id: 'Task11', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle' }, { id: 'Task12', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'dominic' }, ] }, { id: 'lane5', header: 'Testing', label: '()', cards: [ { id: 'Task13', title: 'Landing page', company: 'JCD.pl', price: 1500, user: 'lyall' }, ] }, { id: 'lane6', header: 'Production', label: '()', cards: [ { id: 'Task14', title: 'Landing page', company: 'Google', price: 1500, user: 'jolene' }, { id: 'Task15', title: 'New website', company: 'Themeforest', price: 1500, user: 'michelle' }, { id: 'Task16', title: 'Dashboard', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'lyall' }, ] }, { id: 'lane7', header: 'Completed', label: '()', cards: [ { id: 'Task17', title: 'Mobile App', company: 'Facebook', price: 1500, user: 'john' }, { id: 'Task18', title: 'New website', company: 'Symu.co', price: 1500, user: 'michelle' }, ] },] }

var filter = c => data.lanes.reduce((a, v) => 
              (a.push( { ...v, cards: v.cards.filter(v => v.company == c) } ), a), [])

console.log( filter('Symu.co') )
```